# How to auto set screen option defaults

Tags: theme-development, admin

I want to make a function in my theme, which sets some things in the screen options tab on by default if you select my theme. This remains same for all users in the admin area.

I don't care about their order, basically I just want to make sure custom fields and excerpt are ticked by default on the new/edit posts page.

I've looked around alot but everything goes over my head and isn't working, I'm kind of new to wordpress so sorry if I didn't use the proper terms.

Comment: Please show your code - it's a prerequisite for asking questions on this site. Thank you.

Comment: @kaiser ,I don't see which code to put in, I just can't find how to do what I want, there's no error of any sort

Comment: and I don't understand whatever solutions I find so I can't customize them, nor do they work, nor do they seem relevant to exactly what I want.

Comment: Showing what you've research and/or tried makes easy to whomever's willing to answer to provide an exact solution (instead of trial/error). In most of the cases, this is Stack Exchange's policy, and motive to down vote, vote to close. That said, take a look at [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22screen+options%22) and [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Badd_filter+%2Bget_user_option) search results.

Comment: Note: the post I marked as a possible duplicate is actually the opposite of yours-- the request it is to uncheck a box-- but the approach should be the same. Also, as far as I know, screen options are global, not theme specific and are set per user so what you are doing strikes me as a bit unfriendly especially if you alter values already chosen by a user.

Comment: @s_ha_dum you can modify defaults only, I concur that that question covers topic thoroughly

Comment: Yeah, I know you can alter the defaults only-- answers in the duplicate question explain how. I just don't know if that is what the OP is trying to do, or if the OP even realizes it could be an issue.

Comment: I guess it is very unnecessary, I was only asking because the 'possible duplicate' looks like chinese to me and I didn't see how to tailor it to my needs, since I'm really new to Wordpress, close the question if you want.